# How to send a separate array inside Laravel eloquent with function?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have written as below in my code in LineSheet controller and the items function is in LineSheet model, and I have an array call $seasons. Now I need to send this $seasons array with **items**

**LineSheet Controller:**

```
$linesheetItems = LineSheetItem::select('linesheet_id', 'items.season', 'items.amt_item')
    ->join('items', function ($join) {
        $join->on('items.amt_item', '=', 'linesheet_items.item_code');
        $join->on('items.company', '=', 'linesheet_items.company');
        $join->on('items.division', '=', 'linesheet_items.division');
    })
    ->where('linesheet_items.linesheet_id', '=', $id)
    ->groupBy('items.amt_item', 'items.season')
    ->get();

foreach ($linesheetItems as $linesheetItem) {
    $seasons[] = Season::where('code', $linesheetItem['season'])->first();
}

$linesheet = LineSheet::where('linesheet.id', '=', $id)
    ->select('linesheet.*')->with(['items', 'creator:id,username', 'updater:id,username'])
    ->first();
```

**LineSheet Model:**

```
public function items()
{
    return $this->hasMany('\App\Models\LineSheetItem', 'linesheet_id', 'id')
        ->join('items', function ($join) {
            $join->on('items.amt_item', '=', 'linesheet_items.item_code');
            $join->on('items.company', '=', 'linesheet_items.company');
            $join->on('items.division', '=', 'linesheet_items.division');
        })
        ->join('inventory_items', function ($join) {
            $join->on('inventory_items.item', '=', 'linesheet_items.item_code');
            $join->on('inventory_items.company', '=', 'linesheet_items.company');
            $join->on('inventory_items.division', '=', 'linesheet_items.division');
        })
        ->select('linesheet_items.linesheet_id', 'items.id', 'items.amt_item', 'items.image_name',
            'items.company', 'items.division', 'items.color_description', 'items.item_description',
            'items.season', 'items.wholesale_price', 'items.retail_price', 'items.color_code',
            'items.vendor_desc', 'items.vendor_code', 'inventory_items.on_hand', 'inventory_items.cost',
            'items.brand', 'items.category_code', 'items.category', 'items.fabric_code', 'items.fabric_desc')
        ->groupBy('linesheet_items.item_code', 'linesheet_items.company', 'linesheet_items.division');
}
```

with **items** I need to attach my $seasons array also and get a response as below

I expect a final output as below:

```
"items": [
    {
        "linesheet_id": 44,
        "id": 61,
        "amt_item": "PS839730WT",
        "image_name": "image_name",
        "company": "01",
        "division": "PAP",
        "color_description": "colordes1",
        "item_description": "itemdes1",
        "season": "S1",
        "wholesale_price": "100",
        "retail_price": "100",
        "color_code": "colorcode1",
        "vendor_desc": "vendor_desc",
        "vendor_code": "vendor_code",
        "on_hand": "40",
        "cost": "3.70",
        "brand": "brand",
        "category_code": "category",
        "category": "category1",
        "fabric_code": "code1",
        "fabric_desc": "fabric_desc",
        seasons: [
            //array elements
        ]
    }
]
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: I have read your question 5 times now and I still have no idea what you are talking about.  Please rephrase your question and specify your problem. What exactly is the challenge here? Formatting? Retrieving? Querying? What is `$seasons` even supposed to be? Where does it come from? How is the code even related to the output? What do you mean by "sending"? Send what? Send how? Frome where? To where?

Comment: thank you for the response. $seasons is an array I already have in my code, please check how am expecting my final result. I need to attach $seasons array with it.

Comment: so you are json encoding the response of your  LineSheet model in this items array of objects and want to attach seasons which come from some other logic from your controller

Comment: If this is to send a specific JSON response then I suggest you use [resources](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources)

Comment: thank you for responding to my question, question is edited. please check.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `belongsTo` relationship and then eager load them. A LineSheetItem seems to belong to a Session.

So you can do `LineSheetItem::with('season')->get()`.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading